# Threadpool multi-queue job dispatch algorithm

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, threadpool

I'm curious to know if there is a widely accepted solution for managing thread resources in a threadpool given the following scenario/constraints:

1. Incoming jobs are all of the same
   nature and could be processed by any
   thread in the pool.
2. Incoming jobs
   will be 'bucketed' into different
   queues based on some attribute of
   the incoming job such that all jobs
   going to the same bucket/queue MUST
   be processed serially.
3. Some buckets will be less busy than
   others at different points during
   the lifetime of the program.

My question is on the theory behind a threadpool's implementation. What algorithm could be used to efficiently allocate available threads to incoming jobs across all buckets?

**Edit**: Another design goal would be to eliminate as much latency as possible between a job being enqueued and it being picked up for processing, assuming there are available idle threads.

**Edit2**: In the case I'm thinking of there are a relatively large number of queues (50-100) which have unpredictable levels of activity, but probably only 25% of them will be active at any given time.

The first (and most costly) solution I can think of is to simply have 1 thread assigned to each queue. While this will ensure incoming requests are picked up immediately, it is obviously inefficient.

The second solution is to combine the queues together based on expected levels of activity so that the number of queues is inline with the number of threads in the pool, allowing one thread to be assigned to each queue. The problem here will be that incoming jobs, which otherwise could be processed in parallel, will be forced to wait on each other.

The third solution is to create the maximum number of queues, one for each set of jobs that must be processed serially, but only allocate threads based on the number of queues we expect to be busy at any given time (which could also be adjusted by the pool at runtime). So this is where my question comes in: Given that we have more queues than threads, how does the pool go about allocating idle threads to incoming jobs in the most efficient way possible?

I would like to know if there is a widely accepted approach. Or if there are different approaches - who makes use of which one? What are the advantages/disadvantages, etc?

**Edit3**:This might be best expressed in pseudo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably eliminate nr. 2 from your specification. All you really need to comply to is that threads take up buckets and process the queues inside the buckets in order. It makes no sense to process a serialized queue with another threadpool or do some serialization of tasks in parallel. Thus your spec simply becomes that the threads iterate the fifo in the buckets and it's up to the poolmanager to insert properly constructed buckets. So your bucket will be:

```
struct task_bucket
{
    void *ctx; // context relevant data
    fifo_t *queue; // your fifo
};
```

Then it's up to you to make the threadpool smart enough to know what to do on each iteration of the queue. For example the ctx can be a function pointer and the queue can contain data for that function, so the worker thread simply calls the function on each iteration with the provided data.

Reflecting the comments:
If the size of the bucket list is known before hand and isn't likely to change during the lifetime of the program, you'd need to figure out if that is important to you. You will need some way for the threads to select a bucket to take. The easiest way is to have a FIFO queue that is filled by the manager and emptied by the threads. Classic reader/writer.

Another possibility is a heap. The worker removes the highest priority from the heap and processes the bucket queue. Both removal by the workers and insertion by the manager reorders the heap so that the root node is the highest priority.

Both these strategies assume that the workers throw away the buckets and the manager makes new ones.

If keeping the buckets is important, you run the risk of workers only attending to the last modified task, so the manager will either need to reorder the bucket list or modify priorities of each bucket and the worker iterates looking for the highest priority. It is important that memory of ctx remains relevant while threads are working or threads will have to copy this as well. Workers can simply assign the queue locally and set queue to NULL in the bucket.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is on how to distribute threads across the buckets when #threads < #buckets. What happens when a thread finishes all the jobs in it's queue? How does it know what bucket to start processing next?

Comment: same deal. Fifo or heap and extract the root. Fifo if first in first out is the preferred ordering, heap if you have some priority in mind. Static storage for the task list does not strike me as practical, but it's possible if you don't remove buckets but mark them as done.

Comment: I see. Maybe this is simpler than I thought. The buckets would be known at startup (probably based on some db or config), but they would exist throughout the lifetime of the pool. By static do you mean known at compile time?

Comment: It might help if you changed the answer body to reflect your 2nd comment. As it stands I don't feel the answer addresses the root of my question.

Comment: The idea of using a queue (or heap) of buckets managed by the pool itself, with workers waiting on this structure seems a good way to go. However, I believe your last statement about the workers copying the queue data from the bucket before working on those jobs could allow for out-of-order processing -- if a new job is enqueued into that bucket and picked up by another thread before the first thread completes its jobs. The bucket would have to remain locked until the first thread gave it back to the pool... I like where this is going though.

Comment: ... this actually gave me a good idea. What if we use a heap to store the buckets. When a bucket is picked up by an idle thread, it will only process the jobs in the queue at that point in time. Anything enqueued after it started will be left in the queue and the bucket will be handed back to the pool. Now if we use a timestamp of some kind of the oldest job in the bucket as the heap's priority key, the bucket who's first job is the oldest would always be picked up next. This would eliminate the starvation problem I believe... maybe I'll write this out in pseudocode tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

ADDED: I now tend to agree that you might start simple and just keep a separate thread for each bucket, and only if this simple solution is understood to have problems you look for something different. And a better solution might depend on what exactly problems the simple one causes.

In any case, I leave my initial answer below, appended with an afterthought.

---

You can make a special global queue of "job is available in bucket X" signals.

All idle workers would wait on this queue, and when a signal is put into the queue one thread will take it and proceed to the corresponding bucket to process jobs there until the bucket becomes empty.

When an incoming job is submitted into an in-order bucket, it should be checked whether a worker thread is assigned to this bucket already. If assigned, the new job will be eventually processed by this worker thread, so no signal should be sent. If not worker is assigned, check whether the bucket is empty or not. If empty, place a signal into the global signal queue that a new job has arrived in this bucket; if not empty, such a signal should have been made already and a worker thread should soon arrive, so do nothing.

ADDED: I got a thought that my idea above can cause starvation for some jobs if the number of threads is less than the number of "active" buckets **and** there is a non-ending flow of incoming tasks. If all threads are already busy and a new job arrives into a bucket that is not yet served, it may take long time before a thread is freed to work on this new job. So there is a need to check if there are idle workers, and if not, create a new one... which adds more complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure what value the signal construct adds. Why not just use the buckets directly? That would seem to eliminate the need for all of the checks when enqueuing a job.

Comment: @objectiveGeek: If you use a thread per bucket then yes, the thread can just wait on its bucket directly. If using less threads than buckets, you need some way to dispatch incoming jobs, or some way for idle threads to find jobs.

Comment: you do need a way to dispatch, I just think the signal concept adds complexity with little value. See @Mel 's answer. I think you can keep track of the buckets directly without performing all of the checks that you mentioned.

Comment: +1 Yep: Keep it simple; Improve on that when you need to; and then only with a specification of what exactly the design contract is for these task queues and the tasks they contain.

Comment: I take back my previous statement. You do need the checks you mentioned. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Keep it Simple:** I'd use 1 thread per queue.  Simplicity is worth a lot, and threads are quite cheap.  100 threads won't be an issue on most OS's.

By using a thread per queue, you also get a real scheduler.  If a thread blocks (depends on what you're doing), another thread can be queued.  You won't get deadlock until every single one blocks.  The same cannot be said if you use fewer threads - if the queues the threads happen to be servicing block, then even if other queues are "runnable" and even if these other queue's might *unblock* the blocked threads, you'll have deadlock.

Now, in particular scenarios, using a threadpool may be worth it.  But then you're talking about optimizing a particular system, and the details matter.  How expensive are threads?  How good is the scheduler?  What about blocking?  How long are the queues, how frequently updated, etc.

So in general, with just the information that you have around 100 queues, I'd just go for a thread per queue.  Yes, there's some overhead: all solutions will have that.  A threadpool will introduce synchronization issues and overhead.  And the overhead of a limited number of threads is fairly minor.  You're mostly talking about around 100MB of address space - not necessarily memory.  If you know most queues will be idle, you could further implement an optimization to stop threads on empty queues and start them when needed (but beware of race conditions and thrashing).

Comment: I agree that this might be a viable solution if you consider the program in a vacuum. However, will the unnecessary thread creation have adverse affects on the overall system resources and create scheduling issues for the OS when the number of threads system wide greatly outnumbers the number of cores in the system? In systems that I've dealt with there maybe 100s of these types of processes on a single machine, all having their own multi-queue threadpools. I'm really interested in understanding how a multi-queue thread-pool would solve this problem.

Comment: right; but now you're dealing with an *entirely different problem*.  If you've got hundreds of processes each with hundreds of queues, is process internal threadpooling worth it at all?  Should you be using 100s of processes in the first place?

Comment: If you've got that many queues on a system 10000-100000, I'm assuming most will be empty - why not simply start a thread per non-empty queue?  I seriously don't think you'll find a meaningful *general* answer to this problem.  Anything less than 1 thread per queue might deadlock in the general case...

Comment: At an enterprise level 100 processes isn't that many, and I never said 100s of queues - I said 50-100. These are large machines with 32-64 cores. That said you wouldn't want to start up 100 threads per process if you only needed 25 (or less). I know this isn't an obscure problem, there are multi-queue threadpools available that allow you to put a lower and upper limit on the number of processing threads. I'm trying to get some insight into how they work. This design does not mean their will be deadlock or starvation. See the discussion on @Mel 's post.

Comment: Eamon, I'm confused by this statement "if the queues the threads happen to be servicing block, then even if other queues are "runnable" and even if these other queue's might unblock the blocked threads, you'll have deadlock." If this were possible this would seem to be an application level defect. I don't see how deadlock can occur if the application correctly manages shared resources and correctly designs its jobs to be independent units of work, making no assumptions about how the threadpool dispatches them (other than guaranteed order).

Comment: Assume the threadpool eventually is in a situation in which it runs tasks 1-N.  However, at this point of execution, each task is waiting for some shared resource (not necessarily the same one).  These shared resources will be released by tasks N+1...?.  If you run this system with threads, it'll work - when threads block, other threads get scheduled; the shared resources get unlocked, and everything works out.  It's a corner case, but it's not actually that uncommon - you get this e.g. with any barrier synchronization.

Comment: ...the point is, anyhow, that you need to specify more precisely what is "OK", and what is expected behavior.  If you want complete generality, you'll end up with something that's equivalent to threads.

Comment: Eamon, I'm sorry but I still don't understand you're point (maybe I'm just being dense). It seems incorrect for the application to rely on a job that has not been picked up in order for jobs already in progress to complete. The only thing a multi-queue threadpool needs to guarantee is the order in which jobs in the same queue are processed. Given this you can design your application such that a deadlock is not possible.

Comment: The reason for the downvote is because I think your answer essentially avoided the question by saying there is no general solution. It's possible this model isn't as widely used as I thought, however the company that I work for has developed significant frameowrks in-house, one of them being a mult-queue threadpool which is being used in a number of different contexts. I was trying to get some insight as to how other frameworks and/or languages would solve this problem, but maybe they don't. I can't seem to find any references in Boost for C++ or in any of the Java APIs.

Comment: Consider the [barrier sync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29) case again: here each task much reach the barrier before *any* task can pass it.  Obviously this implies all tasks participating in that barrier must be started and not terminated simultaneously.  They don't need to be running, however; they can be locked.  If your barrier contains more tasks than your threadpool does threads, you'll have a deadlock.

Comment: Also consider that threads aren't magically expensive for no reason whatsoever.  They're expensive (and not even that expensive) because they're general.  If you can come up with a solution that can solve the same problems but more efficiently - well, why isn't the OS using that implementation?

Comment: I understand the barrier case, this is up to the application to design properly. There are many other ways the application could cause a deadlock. Threadpools impose certain constraints on the jobs they are processing. The applications must abide by them, or choose another tool. I'm not asking about a solution for general thread scheduling, I'm looking for a multi-queue threadpool implementation - which isn't apart of POSIX or OpenMP spec. It's a tool to solve a slightly more specific problem, given assumptions that are common; namely, processing of sufficiently independent units of work.